# updates nested objects having array and object keys are dynamically coming

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one situation in which i need to execute query in which there is a dynamic key generation to add data in array something like

```
var tp = 'unique_key';
db.sr_caller_info.update({caller:9967771131, month:201501},{$push :{ data:{tp:{
    "abc" : 12,
    "xyz" : 30,
    "start_epoch" : "",
    "answer_epoch" : "",
    "end_epoch" : "",
    "file" : "xxx",
}}}})
```

My DB Structure is as follows

```
{
  "caller": xxxxx,
  "circle": "xxxx",
  "data": {
    "unique_key1": [
      {
        "abc": 12,
        "xyz": 30,
        "start_epoch": "",
        "answer_epoch": "",
        "end_epoch": "",
        "file": "xxx",

      },
      {
        "abc": 12,
        "xyz": 30,
        "start_epoch": "",
        "answer_epoch": "",
        "end_epoch": "",
        "file": "xxx",

      }
    ],
    "unique_key": [
      {
        "abc": 12,
        "xyz": 30,
        "start_epoch": "",
        "answer_epoch": "",
        "end_epoch": "",
        "file": "xxx",

      },
      {
        "abc": 12,
        "xyz": 30,
        "start_epoch": "",
        "answer_epoch": "",
        "end_epoch": "",
        "file": "xxx",

      },
      {
        "abc": 12,
        "xyz": 30,
        "start_epoch": "",
        "answer_epoch": "",
        "end_epoch": "",
        "file": "xxx",

      }
    ]
  },
  "month": 201501
}
```

I am using nodejs mongo driver 1.4
So i want to basically make an update by creating dynamic nested key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this :

```
var actual_obj = 'obj2';
var mongoPushObj = {};
pushObj[actual_obj + '.array'] = { "namefield": "text3" };

db.collection('mongoCollection').update({ 'id':1234 }, { $push: pushObj });
```